# How to find matrix multiplications like AB = 10A+B?

Tags: matrices, matrix-decomposition

saw this one.

[image]

How do we find others (not necessarily 2 by 2)?
How do we generalize it?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: You can write the equation as $(A-I)(\frac1{10}B-I)=I$, which is tantamount to characterizing matrix inverses.

Comment: You can just pick an arbitrary invertible matrix $B$ and then let $A = (I - 10B^{-1})^{-1}$.  Unless you intend to require that $A$ and $B$ have only single-digit entries.

Comment: @Sassatelli Giulio You should transform your comment into an answer.

Comment: @JeanMarie I would not know how to.

Comment: If you consider the particular case $A=B$, you have already many matrices such that $A^2=11A$ : it is all matrices having eigenvalues $\lambda = 0$ or $11$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When will matrix multiplication become just "concatenation"?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3990191/when-will-matrix-multiplication-become-just-concatenation)

Comment: @MishaLavrov Thanks. Concatenation is the right word I wanted to search

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any matrix $A$ you can find a matrix $B$ such that

$$ A\,B = \lambda A +B $$

Just solve the equation algebraically for $B$

$$\begin{aligned}A\,B & =\lambda A+B\\
A\,B-B & =\lambda A\\
\left(A-{\bf 1}\right)B & =\lambda A\\
B & =\lambda\left(A-{\bf 1}\right)^{-1}A
\end{aligned}$$

where ${\bf 1}$ is the appropriately sized identity matrix, and $\lambda = 10$ is the specific factor in this problem.

The requirement seems to be that $A-1$ is invertible.

Comment: It would be better to write $A-I$ instead of $A-1$ ...

Comment: @JeanMarie - For me, $1$ or ${\bf 1}$ seem much more apparent since for linear algebra you can treat scalars as diagonal matrices with the value in the diagonals $$\lambda A = {\rm diag}(\lambda, \lambda, \ldots) A$$ Just by context you can tell if it is a scalar or an $n×n$ matrix. However, that is an implementation detail that is unimportant for the underlying math concept. Also, $I$ is a matrix that has other uses as a name in nonpure math contexts where linear algebra is used, and it leads to confusion.

Comment: Thanks for answering. But if one sticks to usage, a vast majority of people use notation $I$ for identity matrix (except in some russian books where it is $E$), and I don't see the risk of confusion, even in applied domains I am familiar with.

Answer (score 0):

To multiply matrix A by matrix B, think of the ith row of matrix A as a vector, $u_i$, and the jth column of matrix B as a vector, $v_j$.  Then $(AB)_{ij}$, the number in the ith row, jth column is the "dot product" of those two vectors.

For example, to multiply $AB= \begin{pmatrix}3 & 4 \\ 8 & 7 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 7 & 2 \\ 4 & 9 \end{pmatrix}$, the first row of A is the vector <3 4> and the first column of B is the vector <7 4>.  Their dot product is 3(7)+ 4(4)= 21+ 16= 37. $(AB)_{11}= 37$
The first row of A is the vector <3, 4> and the second column of B is the vector <2, 9>.  Their dot product is 3(2)+ 4(9)= 6+ 36= 42.  $(AB)_{12}= 42$.
The second row of A is the vector <8, 7> and the first column of B is the vector <7, 4>.  Their dot product is 8(7)+ 7(4)= 56+ 28= 84.  $(AB)_{21}= 84$.
The second row of A is the vector <8, 7> and the second column of B is the vector <2, 9>.  Their dot product is 8(2)+ 7(9)= 16+ 63= 79.  $(AB)_{22}= 79$.

You can do the same thing with higher dimension matrices.

Comment: The important part of the question is in the title. The _op_ is asking about pairs of matrices that have $A B = 10 A +B$ as a property. Not how to do matrix multiplication. The question is poorly written though.

Comment: @JohnAlexiou is right. I am more curious about how they magically transfer multiplication into "addition" (concatenation of digits)