# Interesting Matrix Multiplication - Special Cases

Tags: matrices, recreational-mathematics

I have found this interesting Matrix Multiplication cases where multiplying two 2 x 2 Matrices concatenates the entries. Does this have a name ? Has this been found before ?

\begin{gather*}
Some\ solutions\ to\ below\ eqn:\\
\\
\begin{pmatrix}
a & b\\
c & d
\end{pmatrix} \times \begin{pmatrix}
e & f\\
g & h
\end{pmatrix} =\begin{pmatrix}
10*a+e & 10*b+f\\
10*c+g & 10*d+h
\end{pmatrix}\\
\\
are\\
\\
\begin{pmatrix}
3 & 8\\
3 & 8
\end{pmatrix} \times \begin{pmatrix}
3 & 8\\
3 & 8
\end{pmatrix} =\begin{pmatrix}
33 & 88\\
33 & 88
\end{pmatrix}\\
\\
\begin{pmatrix}
6 & 5\\
9 & 8
\end{pmatrix} \times \begin{pmatrix}
3 & 5\\
9 & 5
\end{pmatrix} =\begin{pmatrix}
63 & 55\\
99 & 85
\end{pmatrix}\\
\\
\begin{pmatrix}
7 & 5\\
8 & 6
\end{pmatrix} \times \begin{pmatrix}
5 & 5\\
8 & 4
\end{pmatrix} =\begin{pmatrix}
75 & 55\\
88 & 64
\end{pmatrix}\\
\\
\begin{pmatrix}
3 & 2\\
7 & 3
\end{pmatrix} \times \begin{pmatrix}
8 & 2\\
7 & 8
\end{pmatrix} =\begin{pmatrix}
38 & 22\\
77 & 38
\end{pmatrix}\\
\\
\begin{pmatrix}
3 & 3\\
6 & 5
\end{pmatrix} \times \begin{pmatrix}
6 & 3\\
6 & 8
\end{pmatrix} =\begin{pmatrix}
36 & 33\\
66 & 58
\end{pmatrix}\\
\\
\begin{pmatrix}
3 & 8\\
4 & 7
\end{pmatrix} \times \begin{pmatrix}
7 & 4\\
2 & 9
\end{pmatrix} =\begin{pmatrix}
37 & 84\\
42 & 79
\end{pmatrix}\\
\\
\begin{pmatrix}
8 & 4\\
6 & 3
\end{pmatrix} \times \begin{pmatrix}
8 & 4\\
6 & 3
\end{pmatrix} =\begin{pmatrix}
88 & 44\\
66 & 33
\end{pmatrix}
\end{gather*}

Comment: Duplicate of: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3990191/